# React setState() not update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

State

```
state = {
    likedPosts: [{movie: '5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816', down: true}],
  };
```

function

```
  handleLike(movieId) {
    if (this.state.likedPosts.filter((e) => e.movie === movieId).length > 0) {
      const likedPosts = this.state.likedPosts.filter(function (l) {
        if (l.movie !== movieId) {
          return l;
        }
      });
      console.log(likedPosts); // this returns the expected object
      this.setState({ likedPosts }); // this not work
    } else {
      this.state.likedPosts.push({ movie: movieId, down: true }); // this works
    }
    console.log("now", this.state.likedPosts);
  }
```

I want push new object if object not in `this.state.likedPosts` array or remove the object if that object in array.

When object exist in `this.state.likedPosts`, `console.log(likedPosts)` returns the expected new array. But `this.setState({ likedPosts })` does not update the state. What is the problem in here?

Comment: That should work - why do you think it doesn't? What's the symptom that you're seeing?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Have you read the answers to the two or three dozen other "React state change doesn't work" questions here on SO?

Comment: Side note: Your `filter` callback should be just `return l.movie !== movieId;` What you have works anyway (or *should* work anyway), because you're returning an object (which is truthy) when you want to keep something and undefined (which is falsy) when you don't, but still, it's clearer to return the flag.

Comment: @CertainPerformance All that is required is to add an object the first time the function is executed and remove it the second time the function is activated. The object is added. But the removing does not happen.

Comment: What is the *symptom* - what do you mean by "does not happen", how do you determine that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance About not removing the object. console.log() shows the expected array

Comment: `setState` works in a delayed manner, all calls to it should be considered as requests that are queued and that queue will only processed after all your code has finished. If you do `console.log("now", this.state.likedPosts);` ***right after*** the `setState` command, it will show the old state because your request to change the state is still pending in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried function adding `console.log("now", this.state.likedPosts);` line to check the state after updating at same time. That is why this problem arises.

```
  handleLike(movieId) {
    if (this.state.likedPosts.filter((e) => e.movie === movieId).length > 0) {
      const likedPosts = this.state.likedPosts.filter(function (l) {
        if (l.movie !== movieId) {
          return l;
        }
      });
      console.log(likedPosts); // this returns the expected object
      this.setState({ likedPosts }); // this not work
    } else {
      this.state.likedPosts.push({ movie: movieId, down: true }); // this works
    }
    console.log("now", this.state.likedPosts);
  }
```

Although the state was updated until the function was completed, the old state appeared to be there.

When this is done, the state is not updated in the same function, but when the state is compared using another function at same time, it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Instead of posting an "answer", **edit** the question to clarify and improve it, and then remove this "answer". This space is for answers only. Posting an answer yourself is fine, but then it should present a *solution* to the question, not a clarification or an addition.

Answer (score -1):

You should never modify/mutate state directly (this.state.something = something). You should always use setState method.

To do something after setState you should use second argument of setState.

```
this.setState({
    likedPosts
}, () => {
    console.log(likedPosts)
});
```

Also, I would recommend you to start using react hooks.